# Java Play : When trying to push data to a closed WebSocket Session java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException is thrown. How to handle this exception?

Tags: java, playframework, websocket

```
try {
    out.write(msg)
} catch (ClosedChannelException e1) {
    System.out.println("Handling java.nio.ClosedChannelException exception");
    //e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

out :  `play.mvc.WebSocket<String>.Out`

When I try to catch the exception using try catch block, java IDE (eclipse) notifies me that none of the code inside the try block throws closed Channel exception. But I am pretty sure this exception is thrown when you try to perform write on closed websocket session (Server Side).

If I am wrong about the source of exception , can someone say what could  probably throw this exception and how to handle them.

Comment: Refer [Link] (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3779). Issue not yet resolved. Had to modify play scala source to handle exception (play.api.libs.iteratee.Concurrent and play.core.j.JavaWebSocket).